# Expression 'this is what we have come to'

Tags: grammar, expressions

I came across this expression 'this is what we have come to', the person was trying to express something like 'this is the point we have reached' and I don't know if it's correct or not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It makes sense to me. Simply [Googling the term](https://www.google.com/search?q="this+is+what+we+have+come+to") shows its use in various contexts. (Which is not necessarily an indication that it's "correct," but at least it's something that is used . . .)

Answer (score 1):

"This is what we have come to" is used in cases where a series of unfortunate or unexpected events have put the subjects (the "we") into a situation that they would not have predicted, and would not have desired.

For example, imagine, in a famine, two people searching through trash for food. One might say to the other "This is what we have come to."

Or, more comically, imagine missing a flight, then unsuccessfully trying to rent a car, and finally ending up in a standing-room-only bus trip for 8 hours. You might turn to your traveling companion and say, "this is what we have come to."

It can, of course, also be used ironically. Imagine the hotel runs out of budget rooms and grants you a 4 bedroom suite. Upon seeing the opulent hotel, you might laughingly turn to your friend and say, "this is what we have come to."